# maya python place image on a plane

Tags: python, image, maya

I'd like to create a nurbsPlane then place an image on the plane. I want to do this in python,  this is what I have so far:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class image(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        cmds.nurbsPlane(axis=(0,0,0),width = 10)
        cmds.image( image=name )

name='C:\Desert.jpg'
temp = image(name)
```

Comment: And what exactly isn't working?

Comment: well it doesn't actually add an image onto the nurbsPlane. I don't know how to add a texture onto the plane using Python.

Comment: You would probably have to create a shader, and apply it to your NURBS-plane. image creates an image widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class image(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        plane = cmds.nurbsPlane(axis=(0,0,0),width = 10)
        shader = cmds.shadingNode('surfaceShader', asShader=True)
        SG = cmds.sets(empty=True, renderable=True, 
                       noSurfaceShader=True, name=shader+"SG")
        cmds.connectAttr(shader+'.outColor', SG+".surfaceShader",
                         force=True)
        img = cmds.shadingNode('file', asTexture=True)
        cmds.setAttr(img+'.fileTextureName', name, type='string')
        cmds.connectAttr(img+'.outColor', shader+'.outColor',
                         force=True)
        # you should connect to a texture placement node and
        # its numerous connectins here
        cmds.sets(plane[0], edit=True, forceElement=SG)


name=r'C:\Desert.jpg'
temp = image(name)
```

This assumes you have turned viewport to texturing and shading. Anyway you really need to connect the attributes to a placement node to be properly done.

**PS:** you may not want to do this, but instead you meant to use a image plane node.

Comment: I think you might be right in your final note, the code works, the image goes up, but it's blurry. Would you mind showing me how to do it with an image plane node? :D

Comment: The image is blurry because Maya normally uses 256 sub sampling by default turn on high quality mode for your view port and see what happens. This is what is intended to happen. By default Mayas not intended as a wysiwyg program. All the data is there, its just accelerated the hell out.